# PHP for loop inside for loop only producing first result

Tags: php, for-loop

I have an SQL table that contains a SponsorName, and HostName. There is only one HostName but a HostName could share the same SponsorName. For example:

```
id    SponsorID    hostID    SponsorName    HostName
1     36           255       John           Jack
2     31           221       Bob            Paul
3     36           452       John           Terry
4     32           245       Trevor         Peter
```

I want to return a list of all Sponsor's "Hosts". To do this, I've created this code: (Introductory PHP coding, so it's probably a sham!)

```
                <?php
                $query = "SELECT sponsorID, SponsorName FROM gaming_sponsors GROUP BY SponsorName ORDER BY SponsorName ASC";
                $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);    
                @$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                for($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {  
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center" class="schedHeaderTime"><?php echo $row['SponsorName']; ?>'s Hosts</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    $query4 = "SELECT hostID, SponsorHostName FROM gaming_sponsors WHERE sponsorID = " . $row['sponsorID'] . " ORDER BY SponsorHostName ASC";
                    $result4 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query4);  
                    @$num_results4 = mysqli_num_rows($result4);

                    for($i=0; $i<$num_results4; $i++) { 
                        $row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4);   
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="90%" align="center"><?php echo $row4['SponsorHostName']; ?></td> 
                            <td width="10%" align="center"><a href="adm_sponsor_update.php?id=<?php echo $row4['hostID']; ?>">View / Edit</a></td>
                        </tr> 
            <?php
                    }
                }                   
            ?>
```

I'd like it to return this:

```
John's Hosts
Jack
Terry

Bob's Hosts
Paul

Tervor's Hosts
Peter
```

But, it only returns

```
John's Hosts
Jack
Terry
```

And doesn't iterate through any of the others. If I take out the code to iterate through Host's, it works fine and displays the list of Sponsor Names. It's confusing me because through my logic it should work, so obviously my logic is flawed!

I also know that I shouldn't be combining business logic with design, but baby steps here! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both loops you using `$i` as a variable in expressions. In the second loop change it to `$j` or other, different than in first loop, name

Comment: Bah can't believe I was so stupid not to see that! This problem has had me stumped for about 4 hours and it was as simple as that!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
 <?php
 $query = "SELECT SponsorName FROM gaming_sponsors ORDER BY SponsorName ASC"; //Select all SponsorName. 
//May be repeated too like in the case of John
                
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);    

$tempArray = [];

if( mysqli_num_rows($result ) > 0)
  {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) { //For all such Sponsors, 
//get their Hostsname
      
      if(!in_array($row['SponsorName'] , $tempArray)) // Check if a Sponsor is 
//already handled here for the first time when John comes, this 'if' gets executed 
//but next time when John comes, it will neglect the if and will prevent repetition.
        {
            ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center" class="schedHeaderTime"><?php echo $row['SponsorName']; ?>'s Hosts</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    $query4 = "SELECT hostID, SponsorHostName FROM gaming_sponsors WHERE SponsorName  = " . $row['SponsorName'] . " "; //Get all hostnames for this sponsor
                    $result4 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query4);  
                    
                    while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)) {
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="90%" align="center"><?php echo $row4['SponsorHostName']; ?></td> 
                            <td width="10%" align="center"><a href="adm_sponsor_update.php?id=<?php echo $row4['hostID']; ?>">View / Edit</a></td>
                        </tr> 
            <?php
                    }
                }

                array_push($tempArray, $row['SponsorName']); //John is added in this array, so that next time John comes, we skip the 'if' statement
                }
            }                   
            ?>
```

Comment: Thanks alot Captain Red for helping me out .. I really appreciate it! Unfortunately it's throwing an error:  PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY) in F:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\UniServerZ\\www\\gaming\\adm_sponsor.php on line 38 ... which is $tempArray = new array();

Comment: You can initialize empty array as:  $tempArray = []; //suggested edit

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)